# Rudin PMA 3.24.c proof question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Does anyone see an error in the proof below for Rudin exercise 3.24.c.  The problem assumes a metric space $X$ and defines a metric space $X*$ as the set of equivalance classes of Cauchy sequences of $X$ with the following metric $\triangle(P,Q)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}d(p_n,q_n)$ (which is shown to exist in the previous part) where $p_n \in P$ and $q_n \in Q$ are representative sequences for P and Q respectively. The part c) below asks to show that $X*$ is complete.  Thank you in advance.

c. If $X*$ is complete then every Cauchy sequence has a limit in $X*$.
Consider the Cauchy sequence $P_n$ with $p_{n,i} \in P_n$.  We have to find an equivalence class $Q$ with representetive sequence $q_i$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N>0$ such that whenever $n>N$, $\triangle(P_n, Q)=\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty}d(p_{n,i},q_i)<\epsilon$.

Set $q_i=p_{i,i}$.  Is $q_i$ Cauchy?  Set $\epsilon > 0$.  Because $p_{n,i}$ is Cauchy, $\exists$ $N_1>0$ such that $d(p_{n,i},p_{n,j})<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ when $i,j>N_1$. Now since the sequence $P_n$ is Cauchy, we can find $N_2>0$ such that $\triangle(P_n,P_m)=\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}d(p_{n,i},p_{m,i})<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$ when $n,m > N_2$ which also implies $\exists N_3>0$ such that $d(p_{n,i}, p_{m,i})<\frac{\epsilon}{4}+ \frac{\epsilon}{4}= \frac{\epsilon}{2} $ when $i > N_3$ as well.  Hence when $n,m>\max(N_1,N_2,N_3)$,  $d(p_{n,n},p_{m,m})\leq d(p_{n,n},p_{n,m})+d(p_{n,m},p_{m,m}) < \epsilon$ so $q_i$ is Cauchy.

Can we find for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N>0$ such that whenever $n>N$, $\triangle(P_n, Q)=\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty}d(p_{n,i},q_i)<\epsilon$? We know that since $p_{n,i}$ converges and $p_{i,i}$ is Cauchy that for every $\epsilon >0$, $\exists N_1, N_2 > 0$ such that $d(p_{n,i},p_{n,n})< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ when $i,n > N_1$ and $d(p_{n,n},p_{i,i}) < \frac{\epsilon}{2} $ when $i,n > N_2$ which implies  $d(p_{n,i},q_i)=d(p_{n,i},p_{i,i})\leq d(p_{n,i},p_{n,n})+d(p_{n,n},p_{i,i}) < \epsilon$ when $i,n > \max(N_1,N_2)$.  Hence $P_n \rightarrow Q$ and $X*$ is complete.